# PrimaryKeyNamingConvention Fluent Automapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions

I have a question about using PrimaryKeyNamingConvention
Suppose the following class:

```
public class banco
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int banco_id { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

and

```
public class PrimaryKeyNamingConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "_id");
    }
}
```

and

```
 static AutoPersistenceModel CreateAutomappings()
 {
 ... Conventions.Setup(c =>
            {
                c.Add<PrimaryKeyNamingConvention>();
             });
```

You can use something like described above? When I try to run an error occurs

The entity 'banco' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).

Comment: My FluentNHibernate version is 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such Ids. But you need to map not only column name, but property [name](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions) also.

[Edit] Code added from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513850/fluent-nhibernate-primarykeyconvention-for-property-names)

```
public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool IsId(Member member)
    {
        return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "Id";
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but could you give an example, follow the link that tells me but maybe I'm clumsy and I could not find a way to do it right

Comment: may not be the best solution but I could correct it using `.Override<banco>(map => { map.Id(x => x.bancoId); })`