# fluent nhibernate PrimaryKeyConvention for property names

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

This question has been [asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408639/primarykeynamingconvention-fluent-automapping) but there was no decent answer.

Is there a *property name* convention for fluent nhibernate so that instead of looking for `Id` it looks for `ProductId` ?

`PrimaryKeyConvention` applies to the column names in the database, NOT the property names.

Consider this scenario:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        bool shouldMap = type.In(typeof(Product));
        return shouldMap;
    }
}

public void TestFluentNHibernate()
{
    var configuration = Fluently.Configure().
        Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString("database=asd;server=.\\sqlexpress;trusted_connection=true;"))
        .Mappings(m =>
                        {
                            IAutomappingConfiguration cfg = new AutomappingConfiguration();
                            m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>(cfg).Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<PrimaryKeyConvention>());
                        });

    var factory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

results in:

> FluentNHibernate.Visitors.ValidationException: The entity 'Product' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).

What convention can I add/override to tell fluent nhibernate to look for 'EntityName'+"Id" in the property names? I've looked at [this](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Conventions) convention page but havent found the one to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool IsId(Member member)
    {
        return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "Id";
    }
}
```